# iterating through multi dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am trying to get the item id, and then all option_name/option_values within that item id. So I end up with, ID: 123, Color: Blue, Size: 6. ID: 456, Color: Yellow, Size: 8. However I am getting the correct item ID, but the option_name/option_value isn't coming through correctly, either blank or just one random letter.

Here's my code that doesn't work,

```
foreach($itemlist as $item)
{
   echo $item['ID'];

   foreach($item as $option)
   { 
       echo $option['option_name'];
       echo $option['option_value'];
   }
 }
```

Where `$itemlist` looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 123
            [QTY] => 1
            [MODEL] => sdfsd
            [IMAGE] => 
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [option_name] => Color
                    [option_value] => Blue
                    [option_price] => 0.0000
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [option_name] => Size
                    [option_value] => 6
                    [option_price] => 0.0000
                )

            [price] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 456
            [QTY] => 0
            [MODEL] => gsdfgd
            [IMAGE] => 
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [option_name] => Color
                    [option_value] => Yellow
                    [option_price] => 0.0000
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [option_name] => Size
                    [option_value] => 8
                    [option_price] => 0.0000
                )

            [price] => 0
        )

)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, you're looping over the `$item` array, which looks like this:

```
array(7) {
   ["ID"]=>string(6) "123"
   ["QTY"]=>string(1) "1"
   ["MODEL"]=>string(11) "sdfsd"
   ["IMAGE"]=>string(0) ""
   [1]=>
       array(3) {
           ["option_name"]=>string(8) "Color"
           ["option_value"]=>string(10) "Blue"
           ["option_price"]=>string(6) "0.0000"
      }
```

So on the first iteration, `$option` will be `123`, trying to access `'123'['option_name']` will issue a warning. What you actually wanted to do is this:

```
foreach($item[1] as $key => $option)
{
    if ($key !== 'option_price')
    {
        echo $option;
    }
}
//or:
echo $item['ID'], $item[1]['option_name'], $item['option_value'];
```

That's why your code doesn't produce the desired result.
If the sub-array doesn't always have `1` as a key, try:

```
foreach($item as $foo)
{
    if (is_array($foo))
    {
        echo $foo['option_name'], $foo['option_value'];
        break;//we have what we needed, no need to continue looping.
    }
}
```

Here's the most generic approach to get all options (irrespective of how many)

```
foreach($itemlist as $item)
{
    echo $item['ID'];
    foreach($item as $sub)
    {
        if (is_array($sub))
        {
            foreach($sub as $key => $option)
            {
                echo $key, ' => ', $option;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But seeing as your options arrays look like they all have numeric indexes, you could just as well try this:

```
foreach($itemlist as $item)
{
    echo $item['ID'];
    for ($i=1;isset($item[$i]);$i++)
    {
        foreach($item[$i] as $key => $option)
        {
            echo $key, ' => ', $option;
        }
    }
}
```

You could replace the `for` loop with:

```
$i=0;//or $i = 1
while(isset($item[++$i]))// or isset($item[$i++]), if $i is 1
```

Comment: I need all the options though and im not sure how many there will be. Could be two, could be four, etc. Is there a way to loop through all of them? Your code works, but only returns the first option set, i need all of them, in my example 1 and 2, color and size

Comment: @user1155594: added a full example of how you could tackle this problem. If you're sure the sub array with option-values is always going to be assigned to the key `1`, you can leave out `foreach($item as $sub)` and jusst use `foreach($item[1] as $key => $option)`, without any `break;` statements, and then you needn't nest 3 loops...

Comment: Your 3rd code example works, however with the break it only gives me the color, not the color and size. If i remove the break, it gives me every color/size in the entire array instead of just for id 123

Comment: @user1155594: sounds to me like you've misplaced the `break`. The last snippet consists of 3 nested loops. The break should go just _outside_ the third loop, inside the `if (is_array())` branch, which is _inside_ the second loop

Comment: @user1155594:Oh, now I see... sorry: loose the `break` There are two sub-arrays indeed (`$item[1]`, `$item[2]`), each describing a specific option. if these arrays are always going to be numeric, you could use a `for` loop, or even a `while(isset($item[$i++]))`. I'll edit your question to a better formatted version of the array in question

Answer (score 1):

This is because your array contains the POSSIBILITY of those keys existing, not guaranteed. There's a few different approaches you could take, such as checking if the key is numeric (seems only numeric keys have the correct array of keys set). But since i dont know your dataset, probably the best universal method is to change your code to check if the key's are set, before trying to use them. So..

```
foreach($itemlist as $item) {

 foreach($item as $key => $value) {

      if(is_array($value) && array_key_exists('option_name', $value) {

           //--- Your option array is available in here via $value['option_x']

      }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
array_walk_recursive($itemlist, function($value, $key) {
    if (in_array($key, array("ID", "option_name", "option_value")))
        echo "$key: $value\n";
});
```

Comment: Note that this requires PHP >= 5.3, and constructs the array `[ID, option_name, option_value]` on each iteration, and, owing to the fact lambda functions are objects, isn't exactly blindingly fast, last time I checked