# How to print multidimensional array values in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have multidimensional array with user values I am using for loop to echo those values but I am getting error undefined offset  ,here is my code I am not able to understand how to echo those values.

```
$user_list=array();  //values stored from table in multidimensional array
echo '<pre>';print_r($user_list);

    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => abc
                [email] => abc@gmail.com
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
               [id] => 2
                [name] => xyz
                [email] => xyz@gmail.com
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
               [id] => 3
                [name] => mym
                [email] => mym@gmail.com
            )


    )

<?php 
     for($row = 0; $row <count($user_list) ; $row++){
          echo $row."<br>";
           for ($col = 0; $col < count($user_list[$row]); $col++) {
          echo $user_list[$row][$col];
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iterating through multi dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851340/iterating-through-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `$user_list[$row]` is not numerically indexed, it is an associative array (with keys `id`, `name` and `email`). So this loop:

```
for ($col = 0; $col < count($user_list[$row]); $col++) {
    echo $user_list[$row][$col];
```

will not work (and gives you undefined offset errors). You should probably use a `foreach` loop instead:

```
foreach ($user_list[$row] as $value) {
    echo $value;
```

Alternatively you could use [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to get the values numerically indexed:

```
for ($col = 0; $col < count($user_list[$row]); $col++) {
    echo array_values($user_list[$row])[$col];
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/aNmJZ)

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop in expecting index as a number but your inner index is a string. So foreach will be better alternative for you to achieve.

```
for ($row = 0; $row < count($user_list); $row++) {
    foreach ($user_list[$row] as $col => $val) {
        echo $user_list[$row][$col].' '; // or echo $val directly
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ef8a00bd524e1dc9c12de9ffccb7c5a5a20e4411).